# ¿Cómo puedo evitar la vista protegida al generar un excel con la librería PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

La cuestión es que estoy utilizando la librería de PHPExcel para generar unos archivos .xls y cuando los intento abrir en el Excel de Microsoft Office, todos salen con la vista protegida. El problema es que para luego importarlos a otro sitio deben estar sin la vista protegida.
Así que ahora mismo me toca abrirlos, darle a habilitar edición, guardarlos y ya los puedo importar.

¿Hay alguna forma de generar los .xls con PHPExcel sin que se abran de este modo?

Gracias

Comment: Me suena que puede ser algún tema con las fórmulas, pero sin ver el código es difícil de saber. Puedes añadir esta línea y ver si los tiros van por ahí:
`$xls->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);` Sustituye $xls por el nombre de la instancia de PHPExcel en tu código.

Comment: Bienvenido JugarThor. A tu pregunta le falta mencionar que es lo que has [buscar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search) / investigado sobre el tema así como otros detalles. Te sugiero seguir el [tour] y [ask] para que conozcas lo básico sobre el funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: @Muriano: La vista protegida no tiene que ver con las fórmulas. Te sugiero ver mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/71764/65) para que salgas de dudas.

Answer (score 1):

La vista protegida no tiene que ver con la forma en la que se generan los archivos Excel sino con su procedendia. La explicación sobre el modo de "Vista protegida" incluyendo cuando se abre un archivo Excel en este modo, así como la forma de cambiar la configuración de Excel para evitar que se muestre se explican en [¿Qué es vista protegida?](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/%C2%BFQu%C3%A9-es-Vista-protegida-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653).

A continuación la introducción del artículo referido:

> Los archivos procedentes de Internet y de otras ubicaciones
>   potencialmente no seguras pueden contener virus, gusanos u otros tipos
>   de malware que pueden dañar su PC. Para aumentar la protección de su
>   PC, los archivos de estas ubicaciones potencialmente no seguras se
>   abren en la Vista protegida. Con la Vista protegida, puede leer un
>   archivo y ver su contenido al tiempo que reduce los riesgos.